# How to record a video in low resolution. In Android OS?

Tags: android

In according to the site android.developers the constant "EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY" is used for control the quality of a recorded video, but when i use this constant, the quality of a record video don't change.

```
// Currently value 0 means low quality, suitable for MMS messages, and value 1 means high quality.
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the quality of a record video don't change

By including that extra, you are *asking* a third-party app to record a lower-quality video. Whether the third-party app honors that request is up to the third-party app, not you. Some will honor it, some will not.

If you want greater control over video recording, you have to do it yourself (e.g., via `MediaRecorder`).

Comment: Sounds like the equivalent of a command-line switch; just because you're passing it doesn't mean that the executable is consuming it.

Comment: there is a camera app can do that? low resolution?  if not, i can try develop a new one for my case.

Comment: @Fabricio: "there is a camera app can do that? low resolution?" -- there are probably several of them. However, the user may not have any of them installed, and the user might not choose one of them when you try to record the video.